# Asp.net Core - UseStaticFiles

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I remove app.UseStaticFiles(), I still get static files, such as my images in wwwroot/images.

For instance:

```
<img src="~/images/banner1.svg" alt="ASP.NET" class="img-responsive" />
```

is displayed when I run the app. Why does the documentation say I have to use app.UseStaticFiles()?

My configure:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        // use yer middlewares

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `Program.cs` file? Also, please confirm that you are not hosting the website in IIS and just running it using IIS Express.

Comment: Your `Configure` has `app.UseStaticFiles();`. Remove that line and see if you can access the file.

Comment: If we want to static files, we must use `UseStaticFiles`. For your scenario, I assume it is related with **Web Browser Cache**, please clear cache and try again with removing `app.UseStaticFiles();`.